# Custom Expandable ListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm new to Android programming.  I'd like to create an expandable list with a custom layout.  The group contains image of my choosing, text view and another button of some sort serving as an update button for the group.  The children layout has a text view and check box.  When I attempted to add a image button to the group it disabled the drop down portion of the list so I switched that to a image view instead to get it working again.  Basically I have most of it working except for a couple of things.

I'd still like to use a second image button to update the group.  Also I'd like the check boxes when clicked to be able to update the image view or image button for the group.  I added an onclicklistener for the check box within the expandablelist adapter's getchildview event but what happens is the 1st image for the list get's updated not the group that's expanded.

Group Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGroupName"
        android:layout_width="434dp"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="42dip"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/ivUpdateGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/update_description"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Children Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvChildName"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="50dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbCheckIn"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:button="@drawable/check_image"
        android:checked="false"
        android:paddingTop="10dip" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Also I want something like that but layout is different. any help appreciated